# Find the Last Digit In An Array

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, int

I need to find the last digit in a array and see if it is equal to zero. Here is the code I'm using;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NrOccurrence 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: ");
        int[] numbers = new int[100], times = new int[100];
        boolean zero = false;
        while (zero == false)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a <= numbers.length; a++)
            {
                numbers[a] = scan.nextInt();
                times[a]++;
                if (numbers.equals(0))
                {
                    zero = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int b = 0; b <= numbers.length; b++)
        {
            System.out.println(numbers[b] + " occurs " + times[b] + " times");
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Not your question - but I've a feeling that the line that says `times[a]++;` should read `times[numbers[a]]++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `for (int a = 0; a <= numbers.length; a++)` will give you`IndexOutOfBoundsException` .Java uses 0 bases indexing which means that an `array` of size `n` has indices up to and including `n-1`.
 
Change it to`for (int a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++)` . 
 Same thing here `for (int b = 0; b <= numbers.length; b++)`

Second i am not sure what you are trying to check here :

```
 if (numbers.equals(0))
 {
     zero = true;
 }
```

but you could simply do :

```
if(numbers[i] == 0);
```

Now if you wanna check if the last element in the array is `0`you can simply do:

```
if(numbers[numbers.length - 1] == 0)
     //do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a method like this:

```
private boolean isLastItemZero(int[] numbers)
{
    boolean isLastItemZero = false;

    if ((numbers != null) && (numbers.length > 0))
    {
        isLastItemZero = numbers[numbers.length - 1] == 0;
    }

    return isLastItemZero;
}
```

And call it once you're done reading in all of the numbers from the user.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if the remainder of a number divided by 10 is 0, then the last digit must be 0. So you just need;

```
if(numbers[i] % 10 == 0) { zero = true; }
```

Hope this helps.